# HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0 - socket-js

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, ubuntu, proxy

I am running into an interesting problem in regards to running `nodejs` on port `8080`.  I have a new EC2 instance running ubuntu 16.04, I've configured `apache2` to run on port `80` and have a reserve proxy setup to switch the port to the nodejs server running inside the `/public` directory to port `8080`.  This works great but, my `bundle.js` package calls the server in order to be updated: `http://myamazonelasticipaddress/sockjs-node/info?t=1486698514348` This continually fails and I am left with the following error messages:

`Fri Feb 10 02:28:51.358580 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 19100:tid 140639517771520] AH00940: HTTP: disabled connection for (0.0.0.0)
[Fri Feb 10 02:43:57.689148 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 19101:tid 140639568127744] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:8080 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Fri Feb 10 02:43:57.689205 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 19101:tid 140639568127744] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Fri Feb 10 02:43:57.689211 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 19101:tid 140639568127744] [client 192.55.192.52:56715] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0`

I thought my firewall might be blocking this but I've allowed all connections to this port through.  I've double checked my `iptables` configs and can't find anything.  I have a `vagrant` machine that does this exact same routing and I have no problem.

I have to be missing something simple, any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: add DNS entry  `myamazonelasticipaddress ` in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I've tried adding my elastic ip address in host but to no avail.  It is already configured to allow localhost.  Nodejs starts up on `0.0.0.0` so this should not be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my AWS security group configurations were indeed correct.  The culprit, was that I needed to add a custom TCP type in the security group to allow port `8080` for the `socketjs-node` to connect.